# Use proxychains in terminal

Tags: command-line, 16.04, proxy, tor

I know that I'm using the proxy(tor) by the precise return of this command:

```
sudo proxychains sh -c 'apt update'
```

However, when I do this in 2 steps, the command's return isn't as precise as before: `proxychains xfce4-terminal`
Wait for the terminal window to appear, then enter:

```
sudo apt update
```

Why?
Plus, if I uninstall tor the 2 steps method still works; it shouldn't !

Answer (score 0):

In the above command, you are using `proxychains` for the `sudo` user. However, when you call `proxychains xfce4-terminal` you are spawning a new session with `sudo $blah` which is now no longer proxied.

In essence you are dealing with a user permissions error. The `sudo` user environment does not inherit from the `$USER` unless specified in the configuration (`Defaults_*` in `/etc/sudoers`). There is no environment variable to maintain the `proxychains` tunnel.

To test this further, you can try

```
# Run this in a terminal
proxychains xfce4-terminal
curl ipinfo.io
# Run this in a sudo terminal
sudo proxychains xfce4-terminal
curl ipinfo.io
```

The above commands will return the same (proxied) result, but this won't

```
proxychains xfce4-terminal
sudo curl ipinfo.io
```